# Axios delete and put requests - 404 error

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to send a delete and put request to my api through axios.
with post/get everything works well, and when I'm trying to send delete/put with postman, again, everything is fine, so the problem is with the react application.

axios instance:

```
const api = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

request:

```
Axios.delete("/",{index:name})
    .then((response)=>{console.log(response)})
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

*put is the same, with another data

whenever I deploy these code i'm getting an **404** error in my console and the server doesn't get the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the axios instance you created with the correct baseURL. Change your request to:

```
api
  .delete("/",{index:name})
  .then((response)=>{console.log(response)})
  .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
```